# linux nasm x64 fscanf

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm, x86-64

I'm new for NASM and Assembly at all. I'm trying to call fscanf from nasm, and it fails.. Please, tell me, where I made mistake? (I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and Intel processor)

```
            extern  fscanf
            extern  fopen

            SECTION .bss
n:          resq    1
fi:         resq    1

            SECTION .data
input1:     db "%d", 0
fi_name:    db "input.txt", 0
mode_read:  db "r", 0

            SECTION .text

            global main
main:
        push    rbp

        mov rdi, fi_name
        mov rsi, mode_read
        call fopen
        mov qword [fi], rax

        ;fscanf(fi, input1, var)
        mov rdi, fi
        mov rsi, input1
        mov rdx, n
        call fscanf     ;<---program dies here

        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Comment: You want `mov rdi, [fi]` or just `mov rdi, rax` since the file descriptor is still in there.

Comment: @Jester, Understood.. Thank you a lot, now it almost works =)

Comment: Also, you need to zero `al` because the calling convention mandates that for varargs functions (and `fscanf` is one) it must hold the number of SSE registers used.

Comment: @Jester Was looking for a citation - found it in the [AMD64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf): **3.5.7 Variable Argument Lists** *"When a function taking variable-arguments is called, %rax must be set to the total number of floating point parameters passed to the function in vector registers."*

Comment: Another my mistake was in printf method. I should mov rdx, [n] instead of mov rdx, n. Cause I want print value of n, not an address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you have it *almost* right.  The only issue I noted was that you need brackets around `fi` just prior to the call to `fscanf`.  In fact, I added the following lines:

```
extern printf ; at top
fmt: db "Result: %d", 10, 0 ; in .data

; following the fscanf call
mov rdi, fmt
mov rsi, [n] ; the integer parsed
xor eax, eax ; required by printf
call printf
```

This successfully scans and then prints a single integer from `input.txt`.

Change your code to the following:

```
;fscanf(fi, input1, var)
mov rdi, [fi]             ; <- Needs square brackets to derefrence.
mov rsi, input1
mov rdx, n
call fscanf
```